# Project builds fine from command line, fails within Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have a project that started in Eclipse over a year ago and I'm trying to import and use it within Android Studio. I've exported `build.gradle` from Eclipse and imported it into Android Studio. The project uses the support library, and while this didn't make it into `build.gradle`, I have added this line manually:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

If I run the build from the command line (`./gradlew assembleDebug`) it succeeds. Building from within Android Studio fails with errors that sound like it's not picking up the support library:

`Error:(3, -1) android-apt-compiler: [module] /Volumes/User/Steve/src/.../android/res/menu/foo_menu.xml:3: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'showAsAction' in package 'com.company.app'`

I just updated Android Studio to the 0.5.9 release this morning. I believe I'm using a recent Gradle. There's this part in my `build.gradle` in the `buildscript` section:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
}
```

And then this in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-all.zip
```

So my question is: why do I get different behavior from within the IDE than from the command line? How can I further troubleshoot what is going wrong from within Android Studio so that it runs the build exactly the same?

Comment: How did you create your project in Android Studio? Based on the error message it kinda sounds like it's not actually a Gradle-based project (Android Studio still supports projects that use IntelliJ's builder though it's normally not possible to create a new one configured that way). You could try re-importing the project and selecting the root-level build.gradle file as the origin for the import.

Comment: As I describe in the first paragraph, I generated `build.gradle` from Eclipse and then imported that into Android Studio. I've done this for other projects in the past without trouble. I've even nuked `build.gradle`, `.idea` and the `.iml` file several times and re-imported. Each time, there's some kind of disconnect and builds within the IDE don't run the same as from the command line.

Comment: I should also mention that I've seen notifications from Studio that claim the project isn't Gradle based *after* fiddling with settings. This is what usually leads me to nuke those files and start over. Is it even possible to un-Gradleize a project? (I don't want to.)

Comment: It's hard for me to say what's going on without having your entire project in front of me. One thing you could try is to have Android Studio import your Eclipse project (and generate the Gradle files itself) instead of exporting from Eclipse to Gradle. The instructions that tell you to do the latter are old; the preferred way now is direct import. Perhaps that will configure your project better.